# Can I use Javascript to change page styling?

Tags: javascript, css

I have tried searching this but it seems that it's not common for a site to only allow for JS injection vs CSS.

I have done some CSS coding on my other WordPress sites successfully but just switched to a more templated provider and they only allow javascript injection and not header code injection. I have some design changes I want to make on this new platform but am unclear on if it will be possible to only use javascript. I have already reached out to the provider and they are not going to assist me in changing the page.

I am wanting to hide a preheader on mobile and have attempted it with a basic CSS to JS conversion site and some googling but I think I am missing something as it doesn't change anything once it is inserted into my site.

This is what I currently have in the custom JS:

```
 function removeClass() 
{ var element = document.getElementById("header-slot-onsite");

    element.classList.remove("bg-color__accent header-top-deck text-color__on-accent row-wrap size__boxed padding-sides__m padding-top__xs padding-bottom__xs scope__global");
}
```

Website is [listwithmitch.com](https://listwithmitch.com)
Here is a screenshot of the header I'm trying to remove:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IGRtn.jpg)

Comment: You've shown us your custom javascript, but it's not clear how, or even if, you are actually invoking it.

Comment: `removeClass` is not a good name for what you want actually doing. It can be that other scripts defined already the function

Comment: There is a section in the site that allows for "custom JS" and it's sitting in there within <script> brackets along with google analytics scripts and such.

Comment: Didn't you already post this question about 2 hours ago? Don't repost the same question over and over. This sounds like a question for the new provider.

Comment: It wanted me to be more specific so I was attempting to include extra info to narrow down my question, I deleted the other question to avoid duplicates. As stated in the question the provider will not help me with my problem.